Making sure that colors are properly placed in graphs
I wrote this code which tries to make colorful patterns on a square grid such that for a given color, all squares of that color can reach all other squares of that color without stepping on any other color.**

First I made the grid:
library(igraph)

create_lattice_graph <- function(width, height) {
    coords <- expand.grid(x = 1:width, y = 1:height)
    n_nodes <- nrow(coords)
    
    horizontal_edges <- cbind(1:(n_nodes-1), 2:n_nodes)
    horizontal_edges <- horizontal_edges[horizontal_edges[,1] %% width != 0, ]
    
    vertical_edges <- cbind(1:(n_nodes-width), (width+1):n_nodes)
    
    edges <- rbind(horizontal_edges, vertical_edges)
    g <- make_graph(edges = t(edges), n = n_nodes, directed = FALSE)
    
    return(list(graph = g, layout = as.matrix(coords)))
}

Then, I wrote a function which checks to see if a color choice is valid:
is_valid_move <- function(position, player, territories, g) {
    neighbors <- neighbors(g, position)
    has_same_territory_neighbor <- any(territories[neighbors] == player)
    return(has_same_territory_neighbor)
}

From here, the color is set (a set of source nodes are chosen):
generate_territories <- function(width, height, source_nodes) {
    lattice <- create_lattice_graph(width, height)
    g <- lattice$graph
    n_nodes <- vcount(g)
    n_players <- length(source_nodes)
    
    territories <- rep(NA, n_nodes)
    
    for(i in 1:n_players) {
        territories[source_nodes[i]] <- i
    }
    
    while(any(is.na(territories))) {
        empty_positions <- which(is.na(territories))
        valid_moves <- list()
        
        for(pos in empty_positions) {
            neighbors <- neighbors(g, pos)
            neighbor_territories <- unique(territories[neighbors])
            neighbor_territories <- neighbor_territories[!is.na(neighbor_territories)]
            
            if(length(neighbor_territories) > 0) {
                for(territory in neighbor_territories) {
                    if(is_valid_move(pos, territory, territories, g)) {
                        valid_moves[[length(valid_moves) + 1]] <- list(
                            position = pos,
                            territory = territory
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(length(valid_moves) == 0) break
        
        selected_move <- sample(length(valid_moves), 1)
        position <- valid_moves[[selected_move]]$position
        territory <- valid_moves[[selected_move]]$territory
        territories[position] <- territory
    }
    
    return(territories)
}

Finally, the results are visualziaed:
convert_to_color_matrix <- function(territories, width, height) {
    color_matrix <- matrix(".", nrow = height, ncol = width)
    color_map <- c("R", "B", "G", "Y", "P")
    
    for(i in 1:length(territories)) {
        row <- ceiling(i/width)
        col <- ((i-1) %% width) + 1
        color_matrix[row, col] <- color_map[territories[i]]
    }
    
    return(color_matrix)
}

plot_color_matrix <- function(color_matrix, source_nodes = NULL) {
    plot(NULL, xlim = c(0, ncol(color_matrix)), ylim = c(0, nrow(color_matrix)),
         xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = FALSE, asp = 1)
    
    color_map <- c(
        "R" = "#FF6B6B",  # Red
        "B" = "#4DABF7",  # Blue
        "G" = "#69DB7C",  # Green
        "Y" = "#FFD93D",  # Yellow
        "P" = "#DA77F2",  # Purple
        "." = "#F8F9FA"   # Empty
    )
    
    for(i in 1:nrow(color_matrix)) {
        for(j in 1:ncol(color_matrix)) {
            linear_idx <- (i-1)*ncol(color_matrix) + j
            is_source <- linear_idx %in% source_nodes
            
            rect(j-1, nrow(color_matrix)-i, j, nrow(color_matrix)-i+1,
                 col = color_map[color_matrix[i,j]],
                 border = if(is_source) "black" else "gray90",
                 lwd = if(is_source) 2 else 0.5)
            
            # Add node numbers
            text(j-0.5, nrow(color_matrix)-i+0.5, linear_idx,
                 col = "black", cex = 0.4)
        }
    }
}

The full simulation looks like this:
width <- 10
height <- 10
source_nodes <- c(1, 10, 91, 100, 45) 
territories <- generate_territories(width, height, source_nodes)
color_matrix <- convert_to_color_matrix(territories, width, height)
plot_color_matrix(color_matrix, source_nodes)
title("Territory Simulation")

When I ran multiple simulations, I notice that this color connectivity rule is sometimes violated:

For example, in the above I can see that there is a block of red, followed by purple, followed by red ... such that some of the red is locked off from the rest of the red.
Is there a way I can fix this problem?
Thanks

Look at your simulated data.  Is the input data frame "properly" connected?  If so, then the code that derives the dataset is irrelevant to your question.  If it isn't, then the title of your post is misleading.  I suspect the latter...

I can't reproduce the issue with the code provided. Please use set.seed() to make the randomness reproducible. Or include the dput of a value of territories that reproduces the problem.

I think this question is quite similar to the one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78986692/randomly-splitting-a-graph-according-to-conditions. I just modified the constraints (docking on the given source node per territory) in my answer to that question and hope it works for you.

The code below doesn't give the full randomness in terms of splitting (due to the use of bfs), but I tried to use rmultinom to compensate for the drawback.
Note that, the code takes your create_lattice_graph as a part of it:
f <- function(width, height, source_nodes, rndSeed = 0) {
  set.seed(rndSeed)
  # create graph
  s <- create_lattice_graph(width, height)
  g <- s$graph
  lo <- s$layout

  # define number of sub graphs
  nrsubg <- length(source_nodes)
  g <- g %>%
    set_vertex_attr("name", value = seq.int(vcount(.)))

  # iteratively partition the graph from given source node
  repeat {
    gg <- g
    valid <- TRUE
    vlst <- setNames(vector("list", nrsubg), seq.int(nrsubg))
    szsubg <- rmultinom(1, vcount(g) - nrsubg, runif(nrsubg)) + 1
    for (i in seq_along(szsubg)) {
      u <- names(bfs(gg, as.character(source_nodes[i]), callback = \(graph, data, extra) data["rank"] == szsubg[i])$order)
      if (is_connected(induced_subgraph(gg, u)) & sum(source_nodes %in% u) == 1) {
        gg <- induced_subgraph(gg, V(gg)[!names(V(gg)) %in% u])
        vlst[[i]] <- u
      } else {
        valid <- FALSE
        break
      }
    }
    if (vcount(gg) == 0) break
  }

  # visualize the partitions
  g %>%
    set_vertex_attr("color",
      value = with(stack(vlst), ind[match(names(V(.)), values)])
    ) %>%
    plot(
      layout = lo,
      vertex.label = V(.)$name,
      vertex.label.color = ifelse(names(V(.)) %in% source_nodes, "red", "black"),
      vertex.size = 15,
      edge.color = "gray",
      main = sprintf("territory simulation (random seed = %i)", rndSeed)
    )
}

Demonstration
Given input argument as below
width <- 10
height <- 10
source_nodes <- c(1, 10, 91, 100, 45)

we will obtain splits with random seeds 0 to 4 respectively





